# Is it safe to use string assignment and compund assignment?

Tags: c++, string

If I have:

```
#include <string>

std::string myString = "Hello";
```

then do either:

```
myString = "Hello World";
```

or

```
myString+= " World";
```

Am I at risk of writing over some other memory?
Do I have to use string functions to add or change the size of the string?

Answer (score 7):

With `std::string`, that's completely fine as `std::string` manages its own memory.

With c-style strings using `char*`, you need to manage your own memory.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it would be that easy.

Comment: This is the main reason why `string` was added to the library.

Answer (score 5):

std string is just like any other container class like vector. They have also contiguous memory structure and when they need extra space they just reallocate memory for themselves.

If you are working with frequent string updates and your strings will grow in time, you can call string::reserve() method to pre-allocate some memory for your strings so that new insertions will not result in mass memory movements

Comment: do you mean *continuous* memory instead of *contagious*?

Comment: @Default sorry, i mean contiguous

Answer (score 1):

Using `string` gives you the luxury of handling it just like other primitive datatypes like `int` `float` etc.

`int a = 3;` can be made to `a = 5` or `a += 3` without any harm

Same goes for

```
string myString = "Hello";

myString = "Hello World";

myString+= " World";
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. unsigned char for example only goes up to 255. Any more than that and it won't work. With strings you can just keep adding as much as you like (until your computer runs out of memory). Though I'm only guessing since I'm new to C++. Adding 3 to an integer like in your example, you're only changing the value stored, you're not increasing the capacity of an 'int'.

Comment: @Tez Yes, I am sorry for not making that clear. I didn't mean to increase the `size` of `int` by doin `+=3`. I wanted to indicate that with `std::string`   you can change the data held in the string using `+` etc. With `char*` etc we need to use `strcat()`...